# Price Change History in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table in SQL Server with sales price data of items on different dates like this:

| Item | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | 200 |
| 1 | 2021-06-11 | 210 |
| 1 | 2021-06-27 | 225 |
| 1 | 2021-08-01 | 250 |
| 2 | 2021-02-10 | 600 |
| 2 | 2021-04-21 | 650 |
| 2 | 2021-06-17 | 675 |
| 2 | 2021-07-23 | 700 |

I'm creating a table that specifies the start and end date of prices as below:

| Item | DateStart | Price | DateEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | 200 | 2021-06-10 |
| 1 | 2021-06-11 | 210 | 2021-06-26 |
| 1 | 2021-06-27 | 225 | 2021-07-31 |
| 1 | 2021-08-01 | 250 | Today date |
| 2 | 2021-02-10 | 600 | 2021-04-20 |
| 2 | 2021-04-21 | 650 | 2021-06-16 |
| 2 | 2021-06-17 | 675 | 2021-07-22 |
| 2 | 2021-07-23 | 700 | Today date |

As you can see, the end date is one day less than the next price change date. I also have a calendar table called "DimDates" with one row per day. I had hoped to use joins but it doesn't do what I thought it would do. Any suggestions on how to write the query? I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `LEAD()` here along with `DATEADD()`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DATEADD(day, -1, LEAD(Date, 1, GETDATE())
                                   OVER (PARTITION BY Item
                                         ORDER BY Date)) AS LastDate
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Item, Date AS DateStart, Price, LastDate AS DateEnd
FROM cte
ORDER BY Item, Date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo